# Select Network Methods in Shiny app

Tags: r, websocket, shiny

When I type **SHIFT + RIGHT ALT + A** in any shiny app, there appears something called Select Network Methods (image below).
The example below is from this app https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/genome-browser.html

[image]

I have no idea what it is, but I really would like to block it somehow, because in polish this shortcut is used to write one of our letters. Do you know if there is an option to block it? Do you also have this feature or this is a local issue?

Comment: I can't rerpoduce the behavior you describe ..nothing happen when I use ctrl + right alt + A ..

Comment: I meant SHIFT + right alt + a. And the window with the app has to be active, so click somewhere before using the shortcut. Maybe this will let you reproduce the feature. If not, I have no idea why I and my colleagues have this problem.

Comment: Yes, I was pressing the wrong keys. I was able to reproduce the case in the shiny app from the link you give, with ctrl+shift+alt+a,  but nothing happen, with the same keys, in my local app.  I found that this shortcut is for the "protocol chooser", and that's what your are seeing. But I didn't see anything about disabling it. A part of the code behind this is `$(document).keydown(function (event) {   if (event.shiftKey && event.ctrlKey && event.altKey && event.keyCode == 65) toggleNetworkSelector();  } });` So if you know well javascript, may be you will be able to do something

Comment: Thanks for reply, I will try to block it with javascript.